# Why does std::mutex throw an exception when I call lock()?

Tags: c++, mutex

If I create a simple program like...

```
#include <mutex>

std::mutex gMutex;

int main()
{
    gMutex.lock();
    gMutex.unlock();
    return 0;
}
```

... the code executes without issue.

However, in another app, when I create a global instance of `std::mutex` and attempt to call the `lock()` method, an exception is raised. (I don't have the exact exception text, but it was complaining about an internal of the mutex object being null)

Looking at the internal state of the mutex object that fails, I see that the `_Mtx_storage` member has it's `_Val` set to `0.000000000000000000` and it's `_Pad` member is set to a non-null value which points to a small buffer (I think it was 0x4f bytes in size) of null bytes.

When I compare this state to that in the simple program above, I see that the `_Mtx_storage` state is NOT null (I think it was `0.000000000002`) in the code that works. What would cause it to be null in my other app?

I'm using Visual C++ 2015.

Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Without seeing the code, it's hard to know. My best guess is Initialization order fiasco. (Is the code running before `main`? If so, how do you know the mutex was constructed yet?) Memory corruption? Already hold the lock? Another thread released the lock without holding it?

Comment: I have the mutex in a .cpp file (global) above the only two functions that use it (defined in the same .cpp file) I have breakpoints on the lock calls so I know the first call is failing

Comment: Would you mind creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us? Code says more than a million words.

Comment: I'll keep trying. When I build simple tests to demonstrate, the issue does not arise. Its like the mutex construction is failing internally.

Comment: If the problem disappears when you simplify it, the problem most likely is in the parts of your program that you remove. Try to remove or simplify your code a single step at a time. When the program starts working again, then you have located the part of the code where the problem is, and it will be easier to debug that part or to create a MCVE around that part only.

Comment: Well, it is the simple test programs (see above) that do not fail. I have not found success from within the context of my non-sample app.  I've used std::mutex before in non-trivial apps with success (VS2013). For some reason I'm having difficulty this time around

Comment: @charunnera Is the code running before `main`? If so, can you replicate the problem if it isn't?

Comment: How helpful would it be for you if I said "there's a solution for this which exists elsewhere"? That's how helpful it's for the people here to answer your question when you say "I've a different program elsewhere which is crashing". Questions formed like this helps nobody, and collectively wastes a lot of time of the community participants. I suggest that you post a [mcve] with your question if you expect it to receive any useful answer at all.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz hit the nail on the head. I discovered that a colleague had added some static objects in another module which were invoking my std::mutex object (via it's allocator) before the mutex had been initialized.  To hack around the issue, I moved my mutex into a `getMutex()` function that declared the mutex as static (to ensure it is created on first invocation).  Everything works and makes sense now.  David, please post your answer formally so I can accept it.

Comment: @VadaPoché While I completely agree that providing a minimal, complete, and verifiable example would have been immensely helpful in explaining the problem, in this particular case I was not able to provide such an example (because I did not know what the problem was and was not able to replicate it in my simple examples)  This question still has value because the next person who runs into the issue will search Google, find this question and say "Oh, maybe I have some static (global) object that is being initialized before my mutex".

Comment: I suspected std::mutex had not been initialized when I saw that its `_Mtx_storage` member was essentially zero'd, but had forgotten that globals are not Lazy initialized by default in C++ (and didn't give any thought to other global/static variables that might have a dependence on the code in which my mutex resided.  Thanks to all for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely the mutex isn't initialized yet. If this code is running before `main`, see if you can replicate the problem without the code running before `main`.

Comment: This was indeed the case. A colleague had checked in code to a different source file that created two static objects (which relied on my allocator class, containing the mutex in question) Those static objects were being instantiated before the mutex, which led to the failure. I've added this to my list of surprise that can arise with team development. :)Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the mutex was member of structure of whom's instance was initialized with malloc causing the constructor of mutex never getting called, allocating with new calls the constructor.